# Is there a symbol for Dark 'l' (ɫ)?

Tags: characters, linguistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

[Dark 'l'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant) (ɫ) is an IPA symbol for a velarized alveolar lateral approximant. I've tried `\l`, which gives the similar, but not correct, Polish ł symbol. There is no mention of it in [A Guide for Processing Phonetic Symbols in Latex](http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb17-2/tb51rei.pdf), so how do I get it?

Comment: The symbol is `\textltilde` from the package `tipa`.

Comment: If you're using XeLaTeX and avoiding `tipa`, you may want to use the unicode method instead: `\char"2665`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's Unicode character `U+026B LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH MIDDLE TILDE`.

See also [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

### wsuipa (PK-Fonts)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ipa}
\begin{document}
\tildel
\end{document}
```

> [image: wsuipa]

### tipa

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textltilde
\end{document}
```

> [image: tipa]